# How to define Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communication (always) with ansible win_regedit

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ansible, windows-registry, ansible-playbook

I want to select `Define this policy setting` for `Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communication (always)` in the Group Policy on Windows Server with Ansible and select `Disabled` radio button. The following image shows the desired result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAJ4H.jpg)

I am using the following role:

```
- name: Disable SMB signing
  win_regedit:
    path: HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters
    name: RequireSecuritySignature
    value: 0
    type: dword
    state: present
```

Ansible plays the above role just fine and prints the following message:

```
TASK [active-directory : Disable SMB signing] **********************************
ok: [192.168.106.131]
```

However, nothing is changed on the Windows Server and the policy remains `Not Defined`. Can anybody help?

Comment: Have you thought about setting the policy in group policy?

Comment: Yes, but it has to be done with Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Group Policy uses different types of files to push out settings, these files are the middle-men that the MMCs read. As such, unless you make the change in Group Policy, you won't see it reflected in it. The registry key itself is the absolute check.